# Unable to get absolute path of template

Tags: coldfusion

I am not able to get absolute path of current template. Here are the functions that I tried:

```
#ExpandPath( "./" )#<br />
#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#<br />
#GetBaseTemplatePath()#<br />
#ExpandPath( CGI.script_name )#<br />
```

and here is the output (All relative paths):

```
/var/www/html/
/var/www/html/testPaths.cfm
/var/www/html/testPaths.cfm
/var/www/html/testPaths.cfm
```

Is there some setting in CFAdmin that I am missing?

Comment: How do those results differ from what you're expecting? It's a bit much to expect us to just *know* how this differs from the file's *actual* location.

Comment: And are you *really* encountering this problem on every version of CF from 7->10? Or have you perhaps been somewhat trigger-happy on the tagging, here?

Comment: @AdamCameron If you know, Abosulte path starts with a drive name and a colon. So I am expecting something like this: D:/someFolder/var/www/html/

Comment: @AdamCameron I am on version 9. But I don't think this problem is specific to one version. That's why I tagged all versions. I suspect this has to do somthing with CFAdmin settings.

Comment: @adilmalik Paths only start with a drive letter on windows, which you never said you were on.

Comment: @Busches .. aah .. I never thought that. In fact that's the answer to my question. I only had access to the ftp of the site. So, I didn't know that the CF is actually running on Lunix. Can you please post it as an answer. So, I can accept it?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted Adil. For future reference this is a case in point of why you should always include your expectations (eg: "I expect a path that starts with a drive name and a colon") in your question, as it makes it clear what the "problem" is, or if you're making any incorrect assumptions, or even valid assumptions that might not be immediately obvious to someone reading the question.

Comment: @AdamCameron .. Got it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path you're getting back is the absolute path, but on a linux server, not a windows server. Linux paths don't have a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the debugging info on our development server, the following cgi variables have what you appear to want.

CF_TEMPLATE_PATH=D:\DW\dwtest\Dan\testcf.cfm

PATH_TRANSLATED=D:\DW\dwtest\Dan\testcf.cfm

Comment: For me, even these variables have relative paths :-( I don't know what is going on.

Comment: What type of server are you on?

Comment: I got it sorted. Please see the selected answer. Thanks for your help.